# Nested if loop in Smallest positive number 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this weird problem, When I run following code snippet, it gives me wrong answer. I am trying to find smallest positive number from 2D array.

I tried combining two if conditions in one if, placing brackets, interchanging if conditions. But while I debug I see, control never goes inside if greater than 0 condition.

```
float smallest(float b[3][4]);
int main()
{
    float a[3][4],result;
    int i, j;
    printf("\nEnter 12 numbers into the array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            scanf("%f", &a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    result=smallest(a);
    printf("\nSamllest positive number is %.1f", result);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
float smallest(float b[3][4])
{
    int i, j;
    float min = b[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j]<min)
                if (b[i][j]>0)
                    min = b[i][j];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Enter 12 numbers into the array:
-5
4
9
7

6
2
3
1

-7
5
4
7

Samllest positive number is -5.0

Comment: Doh! Because you set `float min = b[0][0];` which is `-5.0`

Answer (score 3):

It is becuse you set `min` to `b[0][0]` which is `-5` in your example, so the only number where `if (b[i][j]<min)` is true is `-7`. But your second if only true if the number is greater than `0`. Which is false for `-7`, therefore `min = b[i][j];` this code never executes.

Initialize `min` to `FLT_MAX` and it should be fine. (Although this could be problematic if the array only contains negative numbers.)

Comment: Thanks Eraklon, I made it work for all negative array also, by using simple if, else , suing code below.                                                                             
    result=smallest(a);
 if (result==340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0)
 {
 printf("\nNo positive number in Array\n");
 }
 else
 {
  printf("\nSamllest positive number is %.1f", result);
 }

Comment: Glad if it helped @user3667737. Yes I thought about this solution too, but in this case there is still one case where this fails, when all of the array elemets are FLT_MAX. Although if you know this cannot happen with your inputs then its fine I guess.

Answer (score 0):

assign first positive value of array to your `min` and then use your code.

```
    int check = 0;
    int i, j;
    float min=-2;//this is for case when all elements are negative
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j] > 0)
            {
                min = b[i][j];
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 1)
            break;
    }
```

so your `smallest function`:

```
  float smallest(float b[3][4])
{
    int check = 0;
    int i, j;
    float min=-1;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j] > 0)
            {
                min = b[i][j];
                check = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check == 1)
            break;
    }
  if(min<0)
    printf("no positive number");
  else
 {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (b[i][j]<min)
                if (b[i][j]>0)
                    min = b[i][j];
        }
    }
  }
    return min;
}
```

you also should check if returned `min` is navigate or positive in main.

if it was negative no positive value were found.

Answer (score 0):

The function initially is defined incorrectly.

For starters the function shall have a second parameter that specifies the number of "rows" in the array. This function declaration

```
float smallest(float b[3][4]);
```

is equivalent to the following function declaration

```
float smallest(float b[][4]);
```

and the both declarations declare the same one function the declaration of which is adjusted by the compiler to the fol;lowing

```
float smallest(float ( *b )[4]);
```

Secondly the array can have no positive element. SO in this case the function will return an incorrect value.

Th function should return either an index or a pointer to the minimum positive elements. And if the index or the pointer is outside the array then it means that the array does not have a positive element.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be defined and how in the caller there can be determine whether the array has a minimum positive element.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   4

size_t smallest( float a[][N], size_t size )
{
    size_t i = 0;
    float *p = ( float * )a;

    while ( i < size * N && !( 0 < p[i]) ) ++i;

    size_t min = i;

    for ( ++i; i < size * N; i++ )
    {
        if ( 0 < p[i] && p[i] < p[min] ) min = i;
    }

    return min;
}

int main(void) 
{
    float a[][N] =
    {
        { -5, 4, 9, 7 },
        {  6, 2, 3, 1 },
        { -7, 5, 4, 7 }
    };

    const size_t M = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t min = smallest( a, M );

    if ( min < M * N )
    {
        printf( "The smallest positive element is %.1f\n", a[min / N][min % N] );
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "There ia no minimal positive element in the array" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The smallest positive element is 1.0
```

Comment: Could avoid the cast in `p = ( float * )a` with `p = &a[0][0]` or the like.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are wrong. It makes one pass through a.